# Making URL different from orginal

Tags: .htaccess, url

My site is: http://binodgiri.com.np, when you click on link you are redirecte to: http://www.binodgiri.com/what.php?id=1

I want to display above url as

```
http://www.binodgiri.com.np/change-url/
```

I tried following on .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^change-url/(.*)$ what.php?id=1 [L]
```

(I don't have much knowledge on this stuff.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it should redirect `http://www.binodgiri.com/what.php?id=1` to `http://www.binodgiri.com.np/change-url/`

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /what\.php\?id=1\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /change-url\? [R,L]
```

Comment: Thank-you for solution, it did work, can you please explain what exactly is happening, i am new to htaccess